# Pelican ImportError: No module named 'pelican'

Tags: python-3.x, pelican

I was following this doc to install Pelican http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.7.1/quickstart.html

At this step, an import error was thrown.

```
cd ~/projects/yoursite/output
python -m pelican.server
```

ImportError:

```
MacBook-Air:output dorjee$ python3 -m pelican.server
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3: Error 
while finding spec for 'pelican.server' (<class 'ImportError'>: No 
module named 'pelican')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking pelican version, I realized that python virtual env was not activated. When it was activated, the error went away.

```
$ pelican --version
-bash: pelican: command not found `

$ source ~/Environments/pelicanenv/bin/activate

$ python3 -m pelican.server
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Sep/2017 23:08:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - `
```